# DDD aggregate modeling

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design

I am relatively need to DDD tactical patterns and need help modelling an example app im putting together. I am creating an app that is supposed to help people manage shifts in their stores/organizations.

I am currently working on my first microservice: Membership service (domain). This service is responsible for creating new organizations & inviting users to be become members of the created organizations. The following are rules of the service I am trying to model.

- Any user can create an organization
- A user can create more than one organization
- The user that creates the organization is the initial admin of the organization
- An organization should at least have 1 admin
- Only admins can invite people to join the organization. They can invite people who are not current users by sending an invitation via email
- A user is added to the organization only if they accept the invitation (probably click on a link via email)

So far, I only have 2 aggregate root classes: Organization & User

**Organization**

```
class Organization extends Aggregate {
  private _id!: OrgId;
  private _members!: Member[];
  private _name!: Name;

  get members() {
    return this._members;
  }

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }

  constructor(args: InstantiateConstructorArgs | CreateConstructorArgs) {
    super();
    if (args.type === ConstructorTypes.Instantiate) {
      this.loadFromHistory(args.events);
    } else {
      const organizationCreatedEvent = OrganizationCreatedEvent.create(
        args.id,
        args.creatorId,
        args.name
      );
      this.applyChange(organizationCreatedEvent);
    }
  }

  private applyOrganizationCreatedEvent(e: OrganizationCreatedEvent) {
    const initialMember = new Member(
      e.orgId,
      MemberRoles.Admin,
      e.creatorUserId
    );
    this._id = e.orgId;
    this._name = e.orgName;
    this._members = [initialMember];
  }
}
```

As you can see, the Organization aggregate root is responsible for maintaining a collection of its members. It is event sourced as well. The Member class is defined within the context of the  as such

```
export enum OrganizationMemberRoles {
  Admin,
  Regular,
}

class OrganizationMember {
  constructor(
    public readonly organizationId: OrgId,
    public readonly role: OrganizationMemberRoles,
    public readonly userId: UserId
  ) {}
}
```

**User**

```
class User extends Aggregate {
  constructor(public readonly id: UserId) {
    super();
  }

  createOrganization(orgId: OrgId, name: Name) {
    return OrganizationFactory.CreateOrganization(orgId, this.id, name);
  }
}
```

### My Modelling Struggle

1. I am not sure what is the best way to model the invitation process. Since only Admins can extend an invitation to the organization, would you recommend creating an Admin class and putting the `extendInvitation` method on that? If so, how would the request flow look like?
2. Should I model the invitation outside of the Organization aggregate? Or should it be engulfed in the aggregate? If outside, then should I use an eventual consistency model to add the member to the organization?

Comment: Surely you invite a user, so 'invite' should be in the user context and 'extend-invitations' should be in the org?

Comment: This is sort of the thing im struggling with. Should a method be placed at the performing object or the receiving object?

Comment: You can do this without ever using a single public method on any object. Why would your organisation be exposing its members like that? Members are the sole responsibility of the organisation and nothing else need know about them. In fact, you should never, ever, have a public method on an object. How would you design it then? Your objects would have to pay attention to their environment and respond to things that have happened within it (let's call those things, events), and maybe their response is another thing that has happened (event). Would that change how you think about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that only admin can create it is a "authorization" concern, maybe tomorrow you want to extend it to a subset of "special" users that are not admin of that org, or you want the admin of the entire platform to be able to invite a user in a specific org.

> A user is added to the organization only if they accept the invitation (probably click on a link via email)

It seems to me that the invitation is an entity itself, and I see the possibility to have an "Invite" command on the Organization that can be execute only by admin of the org itself, and will create a new Invite (the email being sent is a side effect of the Invite entity being created).

(I see a good approach having the Invite insite the org as it should already have all the info needed in order to check the invariants, it knows all the users that already joined it)